# Show BottomSheet only when the item is selected

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, material3

I use Material 3 `BottomSheetScaffold` and need it to open when an item is selected to show its content. When the item is not selected, `BottomSheet` is closing. When the user closes `BottomSheet` manually, no item should be selected. Also if user expanded `BottomSheet`, it keeps this state for the next selected item. The code I have is next:

```
val selectedItem by viewModel.selectedItem.collectAsState()

val bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = SheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHiddenState = false
)

LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.currentValue) {
    if (bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Hidden ) {
        viewModel.selectItem(null)
    }
}

if (selectedItem == null) {
    LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.currentValue) { bottomSheetState.hide() }
}

val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState)


BottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding().imePadding(),
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = Dimens.bottomSheetPeekHeight,
    sheetContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    sheetContent = { selectedItem?.let { ItemView(it) } },
```

The bug is: this code executes extra times after user closes `BottomSheet`. And the BottomSheet switches to this states: Hidden, Hidden, PartiallyExpanded, Hidden. How to fix it or maybe there is a more optimal solution?

Comment: I tried to use `confirmValueChange = { if (it == SheetValue.Hidden) viewModel.selectItem(null)}` but it broke the animation and the `BottomSheet` couldn't stay expanded, returning to `PartiallyExpanded` every time.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: Here it is. It has a visual effect when the bottom sheet disappears after it's height is below ~150.dp (while `sheetPeekHeight` is above 200.dp) and I need to find a way to make the animation smooth.

```
val selectedItem = viewModel.selectedItem.collectAsState()

val bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = if (selectedItem != null) SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded else SheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHiddenState = false
)

if (bottomSheetState.targetValue == SheetValue.Hidden)
    LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.targetValue) {
        viewModel.selectItem(null)
    }

if (selectedItem == null) LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.currentValue) { bottomSheetState.hide() }

val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState)

BottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding().imePadding(),
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = if (selectedItem != null) Dimens.bottomSheetPeekHeight else 0.dp,
    sheetContent = { selectedItem?.let { ItemView(it) } },
    sheetSwipeEnabled = selectedItem != null
) {}
```

**The second way I made a combined state and an update state flag:**

```
fun selectItem(value: Item?, updateState: Boolean = true) {
    _selectedItem.value = value
    if (updateState) mainUiState.value = MainUiState(selectedItem.value, uiVisible.value, loadingStatus.value)
}
```

Also added a listener to other variables:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // Combines the latest value from each of the flows, allowing us to generate a
        // view state instance which only contains the latest values.
        combine(uiVisible, loadingStatus) { uiVisible, loadingStatus ->
            MainUiState(selectedItem.value, uiVisible, loadingStatus)
        }.collect {
            mainUiState.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods have their flaws, so I didn't find a proper solution.