# Change state without recomposition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need to change `state` in `@Composable` without its recomposition. How to do it properly?

```
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(currentValue) {
    if (currentValue == Done) viewModel.state.value = null
}
```

**Update** for comment:
This is a subquestion for

> [Show BottomSheet only when the item is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071715/show-bottomsheet-only-when-the-item-is-selected)

Currently I need to resolve this intersection:

```
val selectedItem = viewModel.selectedItem.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.currentValue) {
    if (bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Hidden) viewModel.selectItem(null)
}

if (selectedItem == null) LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.currentValue) { bottomSheetState.hide() }
```

Comment: Could you give more details of what are you trying to achieve? What is the reason for mutating state variable without recomposition? Maybe you don't actually need the variable to be State?

Comment: Made an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
var state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()  //change state to var and you can update 

  LaunchedEffect(currentValue) {
    if (currentValue == Done) state = null
}
```

Addition:
If you want to check recomposition try

```
class Ref(var value: Int)
@Composable
fun LogCompositions(tag: String, msg: String) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val ref = remember { Ref(0) }
        SideEffect { ref.value++ }
        Log.d(tag, "Compositions: $msg ${ref.value}")
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to change the `viewModel.state`. Looks Like I made a typo first time.